# How to fix broken IIS on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis, iis-7

how can I fix broken IIS on **Windows 7** ?

Deinstalling it via "Windows Features" doesn't help. Apparently it doesn't uninstall IIS completely so on my subsequent attempts to install it installer hangs and I can see in Process Explorer that it keeps trying to launch svchost.exe -iis for 10 mins and then gives me error message.

Reinstalling whole Windows with all apps would take me another 3 days :/

Please help.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The message is very informative as it's often the case in MS products :) "An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed!"

Comment: Are there events in the application or system logs that occur around the same time you try to add the IIS feature?

Comment: If installing it in `OptionalFeatures.exe` fails, then maybe it is because of missing/corrupt files. Even though it is a clichéd and lazy  cop-out that I despise, it really does apply here: try running `sfc /scannow` to verify your installation files, and then check `%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` (you may want to delete or empty the file first).

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the internet some time ago.
1. Unistall IIS
2. Uninstall (Windows Process Activation Service)
3. Reboot
4. Install IIS again.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please consider adding your source.

Comment: uninstalling Windows Process Activation Service  helped me. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Old post!!. But sometimes this will help someone to save his time.
This seems to be a framework error.[Reinstalling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/03/04/9459067.aspx) framework will solve this issue. Reinstall framework by going to `control panel > Turn windows features on/off > Microsoft .NET Framework xxx`